# Set UITableViewStyle to UITableView outlet programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, xcode7

Assume, that i have the following ViewController, that have an outlet `tableView`:

```
class CustomController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, ... {
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView?
}
```

`CustomController` set to `Class` property in right controller in storyboard. `Style` of `tableView` set to `Grouped` in storyboard too.
And for now i stuck with a problem - i need my `UITableViewStyle` with `tableView`, witch have style `Plain`. Any ideas how can i achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @katleta3000 [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33170275/set-uitableviewstyle-to-uitableview-outlet-programmatically#comment54149042_33170413) probably solution can be `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`. I experimented with it little bit, and found the way that my `tableView` with style `Grouped` can looks like `Plain`. I just simply create my `tableHeaderView` like this:

```
self.tableView!.tableHeaderView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, CGFloat.min))
```

and now my `tableView` looks like i want (i.e. "without" header).

P.S. I don't accept my answer as correct. Hope someone find a better solution.

---

UPDATE.
Better way is to set height for header:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat.min
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to understand your question. You can change it in storyboard.

You cannot change it manually

```
public var style: UITableViewStyle { get }
```

Maybe you need to recreate tableView

```
public init(frame: CGRect, style: UITableViewStyle)
```

I think you shouldn't use `UITableView` `style` and make your custom or styled `UITableViewCell`

Comment: > "You cannot change it manually". I know that. > "init(frame: CGRect, style: UITableViewStyle)" i tried this way before asking the question - it didn't work. > "custom or styled UITableViewCell" - amm, i need different style of `tableView`. How can i get it with custom styled cell? > "You can change it in storyboard." No, i can't. Because my other screens that use this controller will be displaying wrong way.

Comment: for what? Have you ever seen `TableView` with `Plain` style? Thats my goal.

Comment: @pacification set then `Plain` style in storyboard, why do you need `Gouped` stlyle? If you need some behaviour - you should show it. Maybe `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` is your answer.